# Why for sentence in add_command does not work properly?

Tags: python, tkinter

I try this:

```
def prints(string):
print(string)

from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
List = Menu(filemenu, tearoff=0)

labels=[x for x in range(1,4)]

for i in range(len(labels)):
    List.add_command(label=labels[i], command=lambda: prints(labels[i]))
List.add_command(label="!", command=lambda: prints("!"))
List.add_command(label="@", command=lambda: prints("@"))
List.add_command(label="#", command=lambda: prints("#"))
filemenu.add_cascade(label="List", menu=List)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

root.config(menu=menu)
root.mainloop()
```

and it show :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXpkm.png)

when I clicked !,@,# it print !,@,#

but when I clicked 1,2,3 it print 3,3,3 not 1,2,3

why it occurs?

Comment: Try using `functools.partial` instead of `lambda`.

Comment: Use: `command=lambda i=i: prints(labels[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop does not create a separate scope, regarding variable
definitions, so the `i` variable inside your lambda is not local to it, it's
defined in an outer scope. This means that it lives beyond the end of the for
loop, retaining the last value (3, in your example).

The lambda definition stored the fact that you mean to access `i`, it did not
store the *value* of `i` at definition time. The actual access to `i` to retrieve
its value takes place when the lambda is **run**, not when the lambda is
**defined**, which is why you always see 3.

The usual trick is to capture the value, at definition time, by storing it in a
variable that is local to the lambda, typically by adding an argument:

```
for i in range(len(labels)):
    List.add_command(label=labels[i], command=lambda j=i: prints(labels[j]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `partial` instead of `lambda` like this:

```py
def prints(string):
    print(string)

# Import partial
from functools import partial
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
List = Menu(filemenu, tearoff=0)

labels=[x for x in range(1,4)]

for i in range(len(labels)):
    # Create the command
    command = partial(prints, labels[i])
    List.add_command(label=labels[i], command=command)
List.add_command(label="!", command=lambda: prints("!"))
List.add_command(label="@", command=lambda: prints("@"))
List.add_command(label="#", command=lambda: prints("#"))
filemenu.add_cascade(label="List", menu=List)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

root.config(menu=menu)
root.mainloop()
```

[This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is the documentation for `functools.partial`.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `command=lambda i=i: prints(labels[i])` just solve it?

Comment: I think that partial is just easier and can be split into multiple lines to comply with PEP8.

Comment: You don't _have_ to use `functools.partial`. `lambda` will work when used properly.

Comment: @BryanOakley I dislike `lambda` so that is why I use partial. Sometimes `lambda` doesn't do what I expect it to do (like in this question).

Comment: That's fine, it's just that you said the OP *had* to use `functools.partial`, which isn't true.